# How do I add a string to an array in visual basic net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have been looking for the specified code all day long, browsing through the MSDN libraries from microsoft, but I wasn't able to find or come up with a solution:

Question: How can I add a string to an existing array?

I have been trying this

```
Dim Items() As String
Items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray
Array.Reverse(Items)
Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Items

**Items.add("Add This to my array")**
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately.

My code is loading a populated listbox into an array (reverses the entries, and then cleans the listbox before populating it with the array).

**How can I add to this array now?**

Comment: If it was a `List(Of String)` you could do that.

Comment: how would I need to define it..I was having troubles for instance with this line `Dim Items() As String = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray`
How would it has to look to define Items() as a List?

Comment: Try `Redim preserve Items(Items.Count) 'Adds a new element to end of array. Items(Items.Count-1) = "Add  this to my array"`

Comment: In most all cases, a List(of String) should be preferred to an array. They are easier, more flexible than arrays, yet used/referenced almost identically.

Comment: ...If you will be adding other strings to the collection, a `BindingList<T>` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Items As List(Of String)
    Items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList

    Items.Reverse()

    Items.Add("Add This to my array")

    Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Items
End Sub
End Class
```

almost identical code (slightly rearranged), using a List instead of an array